# JS Sort array of objects with array inside

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a specific column in my app responsible for rendering the status.
I want to be able to sort based on that status.

Model looks like this. Take a look at the below data:

```
const data = [
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors: ["Error1"], warnings:['Warning1']},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors: undefined, warnings: ["warning2"]},
  {errors: undefined, warnings: ["warning3", "Warning4"]},
  {errors: ["Error1", "Error4"], warnings:undefined}
]
```

Sorted data should look like this:

obj with errors and warnings > obj with only errors > obj with only warnings > correct data

I tried smth like this but after some time and attempts I got stuck:

```
const sorted = data.sort((valueA, valueB) => {
    if(valueA.errors && !valueB.errors) {
      return -1
    } if(valueA.errors)
});
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const data = [
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors: ["Error1"], warnings:['Warning1']},
  {errors:undefined, warnings: undefined},
  {errors: undefined, warnings: ["warning2"]},
  {errors: undefined, warnings: ["warning3", "Warning4"]},
  {errors: ["Error1", "Error4"], warnings:undefined}
]

const result = data.sort( (a,b) => {
  if(a.errors && a.warnings)
    return -1
  else if (b.errors && b.warnings)
    return 1;
  
  if(a.errors)
    return -1
  else if(b.errors)
    return 1;
  
  if(a.warnings)
    return -1
  else if(b.warnings)
    return 1;
    
  return 1;
  
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help :)